# Postfix: Get real forwarded-to address

Tags: postfix, forwarding, smtp-headers

Our system is set up such that `*@our-server.com` goes to `reader@our-server.com`. We automatically process email and it's easier/faster to connect to a single account that has all email rather than the hundreds we'd have otherwise.

But in some cases, there are other outside forwarders set up like `email@some-external-server.com -> named-email@our-server.com -> reader@our-server.com`

The middle address (`named-email`) is important for our processing because it defines what happens with any messages sent to it. But I'm not sure how to get this address.

- `To` contains `email@some-external-domain.com`
- `Delivered-To` contains `reader@our-server.com`

Is there some postfix option I can enable that enters the original address into a header? `named-email@our-server.com` is the original address that the server is accepting, seems like there should be a way to save this in a header.

The reason for all of this is that users have their own `named-email@our-server.com` address. Sometimes they want to use their own email addresses so they set up forwarders. But the important `named-email@our-server.com` address seems lost when that happens.

Answer (score 2):

Postfix sets an `X-Original-To:` header to the original address.  In this case it would contain `named-email@our-server.com`.

This header is controlled by the `enable_original_recipient` variable in your `main.cf`.